# Creating a column by using condition of ranges of date and time in two different data frames

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new column in a data frame. The new column is based on the range of date and time by comparing the date of the existing data frame. The first data frame is as follows:

```
Exp = pd.DataFrame()
Exp ['Date'] = ['2021-09-10 10:00:00','2021-09-10 11:00:01','2021-09-11 10:00:00','2021-09-11 11:00:01']
Exp ['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Exp['Date'])

Exp ['E_Date'] =  ['2021-09-10 11:00:00','2021-09-10 12:00:00','2021-09-11 11:00:00','2021-09-11 12:00:00']
Exp ['E_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Exp['E_Date'])
Exp ['Conditions'] = ['A','B','C','D']
```

So the columns date and E_date are datetime64[ns] format.

The second data frame is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df ['Date'] = ['2021-09-10 10:00:00','2021-09-10 10:20:00','2021-09-10 11:30:00',
               '2021-09-10 11:00:00','2021-09-10 11:15:00','2021-09-10 12:00:00',
               '2021-09-11 10:10:00','2021-09-11 11:09:00','2021-09-11 11:30:00',
               '2021-09-11 11:05:00','2021-09-11 11:45:00','2021-09-11 11:12:00']
df ['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df ['Para'] =  list(np.linspace (0,12, num = 12))
```

what I want to do is add a new column in the second data frame based on the date range using date and E_date from the first data frame.

The expected output is as follow:

[image]

This means that a new column in the second data frame is based on the following logical condition:

> Exp['Date]<= df['Date]<=Exp['E_Date]

What can I do to achieve that?

[Exp file here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s0DJw2PLr1NGjkfgjQObUiwHXpyV8cJR/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=101245044375916291553&rtpof=true&sd=true)

[Df file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p2V7bsteecobUNyjdtzhEp6U31z-GSlK/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

Try [`pd.IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.from_arrays.html#pandas.IntervalIndex.from_arrays) + [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```py
Exp["idx"] = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(
    Exp["Date"], Exp["E_Date"], closed="both"
)
Exp = Exp.set_index("idx")
df["Conditions"] = Exp.loc[
    pd.cut(df["Date"], Exp.index).values, "Conditions"
].values

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                  Date       Para Conditions
0  2021-09-10 10:00:00   0.000000          A
1  2021-09-10 10:20:00   1.090909          A
2  2021-09-10 11:30:00   2.181818          B
3  2021-09-10 11:00:00   3.272727          A
4  2021-09-10 11:15:00   4.363636          B
5  2021-09-10 12:00:00   5.454545          B
6  2021-09-11 10:10:00   6.545455          C
7  2021-09-11 11:09:00   7.636364          D
8  2021-09-11 11:30:00   8.727273          D
9  2021-09-11 11:05:00   9.818182          D
10 2021-09-11 11:45:00  10.909091          D
11 2021-09-11 11:12:00  12.000000          D
```

Comment: Hi Kesely, Thanks for the prompt advice. It works well with the sample data frames. However, It threw a key error when I applied it to the actual data frames. I mean  the rest of the codes works for actual data frames except the last line of the code (i.e., a new column in the second data frame. It just showed keyError:
And after keyError:, it is just white space.

Comment: @Zephyr Can you please update your post with the data that throws error (small sample)?

Comment: @Kesely, I have updated the post, which includes the actual data sets. Thanks and sorry for the delay to upload the files.

Comment: @sammywemmy, in the attached file "Exp" file contains several dates starting from 8 sept 10:00, in the df2 file, one full day data for 8 sept 2021.
I am not sure if you are looking at the sample date frame or attached files at the end of this post.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly test it and see if it fits your purpose

Read in the data, and convert columns to appropriate date time dtypes:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('Df2.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('Exp.csv')
df1['Date_TIme'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.Date_Time, format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
df2['Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Experiment Date'].str.cat(df2['Start Time'], sep =' '), 
                                  format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
df2['End Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Experiment Date'].str.cat(df2['End Time'], sep =' '), 
                                 format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

You can do a cartesian join, followed by a filter:

```
df1.merge(df2, how = 'cross').query('`Start Time`<= Date_Time <= `End Time`')

                      Date       T     RH Position      Time    id           Date_Time Experiment Date          Start Time            End Time                    Conditions
61050    08-09-2021 0:00  24.087  69.04     A-01  10:00:00   925 2021-09-08 10:00:00      08-09-2021 2021-09-08 10:00:00 2021-09-08 11:00:00  0.087l/s_Tin_8.5C_0.5kW_Load
61116    08-09-2021 0:00  24.001  68.30     A-01  10:01:00   926 2021-09-08 10:01:00      08-09-2021 2021-09-08 10:00:00 2021-09-08 11:00:00  0.087l/s_Tin_8.5C_0.5kW_Load
61182    08-09-2021 0:00  23.873  67.86     A-01  10:02:00   927 2021-09-08 10:02:00      08-09-2021 2021-09-08 10:00:00 2021-09-08 11:00:00  0.087l/s_Tin_8.5C_0.5kW_Load
61248    08-09-2021 0:00  23.787  67.06     A-01  10:03:00   928 2021-09-08 10:03:00      08-09-2021 2021-09-08 10:00:00 2021-09-08 11:00:00  0.087l/s_Tin_8.5C_0.5kW_Load
61314    08-09-2021 0:00  23.658  66.71     A-01  10:04:00   929 2021-09-08 10:04:00      08-09-2021 2021-09-08 10:00:00 2021-09-08 11:00:00  0.087l/s_Tin_8.5C_0.5kW_Load
...                  ...     ...    ...      ...       ...   ...                 ...             ...                 ...                 ...                           ...
2991059  08-09-2021 0:00  23.058  71.21     H-04  16:56:00  1341 2021-09-08 16:56:00      08-09-2021 2021-09-08 16:00:00 2021-09-08 17:00:00    0.087l/s_Tin_9.5C_1kW_Load
2991125  08-09-2021 0:00  22.929  70.89     H-04  16:57:00  1342 2021-09-08 16:57:00      08-09-2021 2021-09-08 16:00:00 2021-09-08 17:00:00    0.087l/s_Tin_9.5C_1kW_Load
2991191  08-09-2021 0:00  22.843  70.70     H-04  16:58:00  1343 2021-09-08 16:58:00      08-09-2021 2021-09-08 16:00:00 2021-09-08 17:00:00    0.087l/s_Tin_9.5C_1kW_Load
2991257  08-09-2021 0:00  22.714  70.60     H-04  16:59:00  1344 2021-09-08 16:59:00      08-09-2021 2021-09-08 16:00:00 2021-09-08 17:00:00    0.087l/s_Tin_9.5C_1kW_Load
2991323  08-09-2021 0:00  22.693  70.44     H-04  17:00:00  1345 2021-09-08 17:00:00      08-09-2021 2021-09-08 16:00:00 2021-09-08 17:00:00    0.087l/s_Tin_9.5C_1kW_Load
```

This however can be quite inefficient and consume a lot of memory, depending on the data size.

Another option is to use the development version of [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.conditional_join.html#janitor.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/index.html) to execute this - it is a convenience function to avoid cartesian join.

I'm using this, instead of IntervalIndex, as your data has overlapping intervals; if there were no overlapping intervals, IntervalIndex is great and very efficient as well.

```
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import janitor as jn
import pandas as pd
df1.conditional_join(df2,
    ('Date_Time', 'Start Time', '>='),
    ('Date_Time', 'End Time', '<=')
    )
                  Date       T     RH Position      Time    id           Date_Time Experiment Date          Start Time            End Time                    Conditions
0      08-09-2021 0:00  24.087  69.04     A-01  10:00:00   925 2021-09-08 10:00:00      08-09-2021 2021-09-08 10:00:00 2021-09-08 11:00:00  0.087l/s_Tin_8.5C_0.5kW_Load
1      08-09-2021 0:00  24.001  68.30     A-01  10:01:00   926 2021-09-08 10:01:00      08-09-2021 2021-09-08 10:00:00 2021-09-08 11:00:00  0.087l/s_Tin_8.5C_0.5kW_Load
2      08-09-2021 0:00  23.873  67.86     A-01  10:02:00   927 2021-09-08 10:02:00      08-09-2021 2021-09-08 10:00:00 2021-09-08 11:00:00  0.087l/s_Tin_8.5C_0.5kW_Load
3      08-09-2021 0:00  23.787  67.06     A-01  10:03:00   928 2021-09-08 10:03:00      08-09-2021 2021-09-08 10:00:00 2021-09-08 11:00:00  0.087l/s_Tin_8.5C_0.5kW_Load
4      08-09-2021 0:00  23.658  66.71     A-01  10:04:00   929 2021-09-08 10:04:00      08-09-2021 2021-09-08 10:00:00 2021-09-08 11:00:00  0.087l/s_Tin_8.5C_0.5kW_Load
...                ...     ...    ...      ...       ...   ...                 ...             ...                 ...                 ...                           ...
12563  08-09-2021 0:00  23.058  71.21     H-04  16:56:00  1341 2021-09-08 16:56:00      08-09-2021 2021-09-08 16:00:00 2021-09-08 17:00:00    0.087l/s_Tin_9.5C_1kW_Load
12564  08-09-2021 0:00  22.929  70.89     H-04  16:57:00  1342 2021-09-08 16:57:00      08-09-2021 2021-09-08 16:00:00 2021-09-08 17:00:00    0.087l/s_Tin_9.5C_1kW_Load
12565  08-09-2021 0:00  22.843  70.70     H-04  16:58:00  1343 2021-09-08 16:58:00      08-09-2021 2021-09-08 16:00:00 2021-09-08 17:00:00    0.087l/s_Tin_9.5C_1kW_Load
12566  08-09-2021 0:00  22.714  70.60     H-04  16:59:00  1344 2021-09-08 16:59:00      08-09-2021 2021-09-08 16:00:00 2021-09-08 17:00:00    0.087l/s_Tin_9.5C_1kW_Load
12567  08-09-2021 0:00  22.693  70.44     H-04  17:00:00  1345 2021-09-08 17:00:00      08-09-2021 2021-09-08 16:00:00 2021-09-08 17:00:00    0.087l/s_Tin_9.5C_1kW_Load
```

If you can find a common column that already exists within the dataframes, then a merge, followed by a filter is quite efficient, and better/ more efficient than the [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.conditional_join.html#janitor.conditional_join).

Comment: Dear @Sammywemmy, I will test it. I will try second one as it seems pretty simple and efficient.

Comment: Hi @sammywemmy, It shows the following error. 
ValueError:  conditional_join only supports numeric, date, or string types.
I checked the types, Date is in datetime, start time and end time are object. I am not sure whats wrong

Comment: Convert start and end time to date time

Comment: Both columns should be of the same data type. The error message can be beta though

Comment: I have converted start time and end time to the corresponding DateTime format. But still the same. COuld it be due the other columns, the actual data frames for df1, in this case, contain other data types, such as float, object. But in the Exp data frame for actual is the same as posted in the link.

Comment: I have updated the actual data set for Df file.

Comment: still having the same error message? could you post the error message? did you try option 1 (the cartesian join) ? did that work ?

Comment: I have updated the solution based on the updated file; I had to change the time format for Exp to `'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'` from `'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'`. Let me know how it goes.